# How can we add sms programatically in sim card in android

Tags: android

I have been trying to do this using content://sms/sim URI. But i can just access the data base, but not add to it.  I actually want to implement 'copy to sim' functionality in my application.

This is my code snippet:

```
     ArrayList listName=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList listContactId=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList listMobileNo=new ArrayList(); 
        ArrayList listEmail=new ArrayList();

        Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sim");
        Cursor cursorSim    = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null,null, null);
        String[] coloumnName=new String[cursorSim.getColumnCount()];
        for(int i=0;i<cursorSim.getColumnCount();i++)
{
        coloumnName[i]= cursorSim.getColumnName(i);
        Log.i("Coulmn name -------!!!!!----------------",coloumnName[i]);
}

         while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) {           
             listName.          add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name")));
             listContactId.     add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("_id")));      
             listMobileNo.      add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number")));
             listEmail.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("emails")));
            }
```

This just allows me to read messages.

When i try to insert data.

- **Code snippet:**

  //Insert
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  // values.put("name", "One");

  values.put("address", "1111111111"); 
  values.put("body", "Its a great day. Thats is been expected since i was born"); 
  values.put("date", "1312434417006"); 
  Uri newRowUri = getContentResolver().insert(simUri , values);
     09-02 17:35:07.209: ERROR/SmsProvider(1476): Invalid request: content://sms/icc

I have given necessary permissions in my manifest file.
Can anyone suggest me how to do it. I even want to know whether this can be done, are there enough permissions to do this also.

Thanks
Vaishnavi

Answer (score 0):

to read an sms from the phone you can use the regular api

```
  Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                                SMS_INBOX_CONTENT_URI,
                      new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body" },
                                WHERE_CONDITION,
                                null,
                                SORT_ORDER);
```

now iterate through the cursor & get the message

you can use the SmsContentProvider to save the message in another folder.. (say the sim card)

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123456789");
values.put("body", "foo bar");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

ofcourse there are some loose ends which needs to be tied up..

its important to remind you to be careful while using content providers [check this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html)

Comment: hey ,
Thanks for the reply.. But, how to store it to the SIM card. Any specific folder to store to the sim.