# Saving contact to SIM card

Tags: android

i want to save `contact` to `sim` card but i am unable to do that. i used this code to save contact

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(People.NUMBER, phone);
        values.put(People.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
        values.put(People.LABEL, name);
        values.put(People.NAME, name);

        Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(People.CONTENT_URI, values);
        Uri updateUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(dataUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        values.clear();
        values.put(People.Phones.TYPE, People.TYPE_CUSTOM);
        values.put(People.NUMBER, phone);
        updateUri = getContentResolver().insert(updateUri, values);
```

but it is not saving in sim card.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You should obtain dataUri for SiM card contacts not for contacts stored in the device.

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null,null, null);
```

Also your Application should obtain permission to read and write contacts. Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

to your Android.xml file.

Have a look at

[How can we add sms programatically in sim card in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283163/how-can-we-add-sms-programatically-in-sim-card-in-android)

[How to get All Sim Contacts in Android Progrmmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757022/how-to-get-all-sim-contacts-in-android-progrmmatically)

Comment: I used Thic Code and nothing appear in my contacts
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");

  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put("name", "zzzz");
  cv.put("number", "99999999999");
  getContentResolver().insert(simUri, cv);

Answer (score 1):

`cv.put("name", "zzzz"); // Wrong` "name" not the correct key. Use "tag" instead `cv.put("tag", "zzzz");`

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing any Id to add contacts.

```
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, idyouwanttoadd);
```

And for more inforamtion please check below link:
[How to add new contacts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android)