# Android, create a contact at SIM programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to create a contact at SIM(Nexus 5 Marshmallow).

```
    String name = (String)nameEditText.getText().toString();
    String phoneNumber = (String)phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString();

    String result = null;

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.anddroid.contacts.sim")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "SIM")
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    name).build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
            newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .build());

    // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch("com.android.contacts", ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

But it creates a contact at the phone memory.

As the first applyBatch's argument i also tried `"com.android.contacts"`, `"com.android.contacts.sim"`, `"content://icc/adn"`. It doesn't work properly too.

Comment: can visit here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18145954/3073945

Comment: what is your package name ?  add pachkage name instead of **com.anddroid.contacts.sim**

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same question and been looking for answer.
What I do is change the `ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE` value to `com.android.sim` like this:

```
withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.android.sim")
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("tag", "Me");
cv.put("number", "yourphonenumber");
getContentResolver().insert(simUri, cv);
```

Make sure you have required permissions granted to your application.