# Android: how to create a contact and store it in sim programatically

Tags: android, android-contacts

This code executed successfully but the contact is not saved to sim.

```
 private fun addContactToSim(number: String, name: String) {
        try {
            val simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn")
            val cv = ContentValues()
            cv.put("tag", name)
            cv.put("number", number)
            context.getContentResolver().insert(simUri, cv)
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(simUri, null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

In some of the device after rebooting displays the contact added but in some of device after rebooting the contact is not display. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/18145954/6533853

Comment: i tried @Ninja same but still facing issue  not able to save properly contact into sim

Answer (score 0):

It will work for sure I already worked a lot on this

Try This step by step
IF you want add more property to contact comment it I will will give you

```
      ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(
                                ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(
                                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                name).build());

         ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withValueBackReference(
                                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                .withValue(
                                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                        strmob)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER)
                                //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                                .build());

   ContentProviderResult[] res = activity.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Comment: Thanx  let me check your solution i am struggling in this plz let me check then i will get back to you

Comment: but i have to save it on Sim Card only not phone book can you please suggest me how to create contact on Sim only @Maulik Patel

Comment: can u please suggest me  any solution if u have worked in prevously